# Android- Swiping Across Multiple Buttons

Tags: java, android, button, touch

I've implemented a grid of buttons using a grid layout. I'm trying to allow for a single swipe to activate multiple buttons. When the user touches any one of the buttons, I call a function with the specific button pressed to take the according action. But, currently, I can only activate one button per touch. Multi-touch works, but not a single swipe. The problem is that while the onTouch function is called continuously the view object that I use to determine the button pressed is only updated on the initial touch. What I need to do is get the id's of all of the buttons that were swiped across.

Thanks.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) 
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.padZeroZero:
            padTouch(0,0);
            break;
        case R.id.padZeroOne:
            padTouch(0,1);
            break;
        case R.id.padZeroTwo:
            padTouch(0,2);
            break;
        //There's a lot more cases (it's a 9x8 grid), but they all do the same thing.
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you need to look for `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` instead of just `ACTION_DOWN` down only happens when the finger touches the screen, move happens subsequently when the finger moves or drags.

Comment: Okay, so that fixed an issue I didn't know I had yet, and I updated the code accordingly. It now gets to the switch statement on every move, but it still always has the same View v as the first touch, so the switch always goes to the same case.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to manually check the x,y coordinates and compare them with your other Views I think.